# Excel file summation of rows

Tags: python, excel, sum

I have an excel file with different numbers of elements per row. I want to add all the elements in each row and show the summation in a new column. the problem is the rows are of different sizes. I want to do this using python. A program example of the problem would help a lot. what I consider is i can fill in the empty colums `Nan` with `0`.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uzxqh.png)

Comment: Q1:  Where does the new column needs to be ?
Q2: What tool do you want to use :
- Excel formula
- Excel vba
- Python

Comment: the new column can be at the end, and I want to use python to do the sum and autamatically sum up all the row elements and put it into the new column

Comment: @zak3877 if answer helped you accept it as answer:)

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:
read `CSV` or `XLSX` file with `df=pd.read_csv('22.csv')` or `df=pd.read_excel('22.xlsx', header=None)` as `df`. Then list  column in datafram to sum values of each row in all column and save it in column `sum`

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv('22.csv', header=None)
#for Xlsx file use this:
#df=pd.read_excel('22.xlsx', header=None) 
col_list= list(df)
df['Sum'] = df[col_list].sum(axis=1)
print(df)
df.to_csv('33.csv')
```

**input**(csv file):

[image]

**Output** would be like below:

[image]

No need to replace `Nan` or empty values by 0 in `sum`, it works with out it, However if you need to do it, it is possible by `df.fillna(0, inplace = True)` you can apply to your datafarm and it would replace `Nan` with `0`